# 2 Images, same object: tone difference and alignment

Tags: image-processing

I would like to know a software which helps in post-production to calculate the general color/tone difference of 2 images. The images contain the same object, but arn't shot from the same position. One image might be sunny, the other cloudy, so one is more orange/yellow, the other more grey/blue, but the same object.

How would you align the tone of the image?

Background info: i shoot a couple of hundreds of images to produce textures for my models, the objects are outside, so weather conditions can change at any time, shooting must continue. I do photogrammetry, so I use the images to project them on the geometry and bake them in a UV Map. So in general I have a chunk of images made in sunny condition and another in cloudy. I would like to apply a tone to all cloudy images, having similar tone like in the sunny images.

It's not about HDR. It should be computable, not manually.

Comment: This is CGI, texture generation, scientific measurements, etc.

Comment: what you are after is the albedo map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (and perhaps "proper") way to do this is to use a color reference card in each of your photos. Otherwise, it's actually quite hard to automate.

In most cases, this can simply be a neutral gray card.

Either take a test shot in the same lighting or include the card in a part of the photo that will be cropped out. If you put the reference card in the same position in each image, it should be very easy to automatically locate and use automatically. There's an example of doing this with ImageMagick [in this forum thread](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=15564&start=15), although there are tons of similar possible approaches with different software.

Comment: Using a color reference card is a good idea! I'll try that the next shooting. For my current project having thousands of images, I will probably use Lightroom to auto-whitebalance them.